# Ayuda con login, no me toma la sesion

Tags: php

Trabajo con MVC y puse una condicion en el llamado a la hoja de rutas, donde si el usuario no esta en la sesion llama al login, es decir no se puede entrar a ningun controlador sin estar logueado:

```html
<?php
session_start();
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/gestionweb/routes.php');
require_once('routes.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/gestionweb/views/template.php');
if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];

}else{
$id=0;}

 if (isset($_GET['controller'])&&isset($_GET['action'])) {
  $controller=$_GET['controller'];
  $action=$_GET['action'];
   
        call($controller,$action,$id);  
 }
}else{
    echo "no existe";
    call("login","index",0);
}
?>
```

De la seguridad me voy a encargar despues,quiero que me funcione la sesion.
El caso es que siempre redirige al login:

```html
<?php
require_once ("C:\\xampp\htdocs\gestionweb\includes\claseConexion.php");

class Login{
  private $estado;
  private $idp;

public function __construct(){
  
   } 

public function User($usuario,$pass)
 {
  try
  {
            $conexion = Conexion::singleton_conexion();
   

   $stm=$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM despensa.usuarios WHERE nombre='".$usuario."' AND pass='".$pass."';");
        
              $stm->execute();
           $array=$stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
           
           if ($array>0){ 
                foreach ($array as $n){
                  
                session_start();
            $_SESSION['usuario']=$n['nombre']; 
            $_SESSION['idlog']=$n['iduser'];        
                }
            
           }
   return $array;
         
            
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
   die($e->getMessage());
  }
 }
  

}
   
?>
```

Y aclaro que tambien llamo a sesion_start() en el documento de template..que puede ser?

Aca el javascript dentro de login:

```js
var usuarios;
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $("#guardar").click(function(){
        var usuario = $("#usuario").val();
        var pass = $("#pass").val();
        $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/procesologin.php",
            data: { "accion": "ingresar","user":usuario,"pass":pass}, 
       dataType:'json',
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(data){
               
        if(data.length===0){
            alert("login incorrecto");
        }else{
           
            window.location.href="index.php?controller=template&action=index";
        }
               
            }
        
    });

         
  

          
});
```

Al hacer click en guardar manda user y pass a php.

Gracias

La session llega perfectamente porque hago un var dump de session:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Osea el error esta en el mismo index:
SI pongo articulo index para que redirija lo abre perfecto el catalogo de productos, pero porque no abre la template de la pagina?

Ademas la llamada queda con estado 302 en la respuesta del navegador.

Comment: dale un var_dump($_SESSION); al principio del documento para ver si esta tomando los valores~

Comment: Devuelve array(0) { } , es decir no esta creando la sesion en el archivo claseLogin? El array asociativo que retorna el metodo User si lo veo en la red del navegador en respuesta

Comment: Otra alternativa seria crear una clase de sesion, pero deberia funcionar asi

Comment: en tu public function User($usuario,$pass) despues de iniciar darle un var_dump para ver si ahi las esta tomando! si es asi intenta colocar un @session_start(); a todos los session_start();

Comment: Si la esta creando..devuelve user y id..voy a intentar con el arroba.

Comment: Lo raro es que redirige como hice en ajax al index de template..osea a la portada, pero conserva la pagina de login

Comment: bueno ya logre que me tome la sesion pero continua en login..no pasa a template:: https://ibb.co/H7WHMvh